# How can I get the shadow.offsetX value of some text within a group?

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to reference the shadow offsetX value of some text that is grouped with a rectangle but I keep getting 'Cannot read property 'offsetX' of null' in the mousedown event of the group.

How can I get the shadow.offsetX value of some text within a group please?

code snippet:

...
    //ADD SOME TEXT TO CANVAS AT RANDOM X,Y CO-ORDINATES
    var X = Math.floor((Math.random() * 350) + 30);
    var Y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 350) + 30);

```
var text = new fabric.IText("This is some\ntest text", {
fontFamily: 'Courier New',
left: X+5,
top: Y+5,
    cursorColor: 'black',
    cursorDelay: 50,
    cursorDuration: 250,
    cursorWidth: 2,
    editingBorderColor: '#F30D0D',
    lineHeight: 1,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    textAlign: 'left',
    textDecoration: '',
    fontSize: 15,
    fill: '#ffffff',
    id: 2,
    fill: '#000000'
});

//APPLY SHADOW TO TEXT
var shadow = {
    color: 'rgb(50,50,50)',
    blur: 3,    
    offsetX: 1,
    offsetY: 1
}
text.setShadow(shadow);

//ADD A RECTANGLE
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: X,
    top: Y,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: '#ffcc12',
    id: 2,
    opacity: 1
});

//canvas.add(rect);
//canvas.add(text);
var group = new fabric.Group([rect, text]);
canvas.add(group);
canvas.renderAll();

canvas.setActiveObject(text);
var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
console.log(activeObject.id);
```

...

Things work OK if I don't group the objects.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When grouped all the objects become children of the group and you need to use the `.getObjects()` call on the clicked group to get the child objects. The below code will properly console log the `shadow.offsetX`

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false, preserveObjectStacking:true });
window.canvas = canvas;
var text = new fabric.IText("This is some\ntest text", {
fontFamily: 'Courier New',
left: 5,
top: 5,
    cursorColor: 'black',
    cursorDelay: 50,
    cursorDuration: 250,
    cursorWidth: 2,
    editingBorderColor: '#F30D0D',
    lineHeight: 1,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    textAlign: 'left',
    textDecoration: '',
    fontSize: 15,
    fill: '#ffffff',
    id: 2,
    fill: '#000000'
});

//APPLY SHADOW TO TEXT
var shadow = {
    color: 'rgb(50,50,50)',
    blur: 3,    
    offsetX: 1,
    offsetY: 1
}
text.setShadow(shadow);

//ADD A RECTANGLE
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: '#ffcc12',
    id: 2,
    opacity: 1
});

//canvas.add(rect);
//canvas.add(text);
var group = new fabric.Group([rect, text]);


group.on('mousedown', function(e) {
  var  clickedGroup = e.target;
  var groupedObjects = clickedGroup.getObjects();
  var groupedText = groupedObjects[1];
  var shadowOffsetX = groupedText.shadow.offsetX;
  console.log(shadowOffsetX)
});

canvas.add(group);
canvas.renderAll();

canvas.setActiveObject(text);
var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
console.log(activeObject.id);
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your concise and very helpful answer STHayden! 

I really like Fabric JS but wish there was more comprehensive documentation on their site with more examples or am I just not looking in the right places?

Comment: groups are described here: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3#groups and there is a large list of demos here: http://fabricjs.com/demos/